# Safari desktop not executing Javascript when user navigates to page with back button

Tags: javascript, safari

I am working on a page that depends on Javascript running.  It uses straight vanilla Javascript, no JQuery or framework involved.  When the user comes to the page the Javascript executes as expected.  When they navigate to another page and return to the original page using the back button, the Javascript does not seem to execute in Safari desktop but it does in Chrome and Firefox.

It seems Safari may be loading a cached version of the page rather than reloading the page despite the fact I am sending cache control headers with the page.  The cache control headers I'm sending are:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Here's a simple example of code that exhibits the same behavior.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>JS Test</h1>

<p>This is a simple test file.</p>

<p id="hideMe">This paragraph should be hidden unless you came back.</p>

<p>Click <a href="https://www.google.com">here</a>.</p>

<script>
    /* Returns the search query variable value or false if not found */
    function getQueryVariable(varName) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i = 0 ;i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            if(pair[0] == varName){
                return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
            }
        }
        return(false);
    }

    var windowLoaded = function() {
        console.log("windowLoaded starting...");

        /*
         * If back is not in the query string hide the paragraph and push the
         * query variable into our history.
         */
        var cameBack = getQueryVariable("back");
        if (!cameBack) {
            var p = document.getElementById("hideMe");
            p.hidden = true;
            history.pushState(null, null, "?back=true");
        }
    };
    
    window.onload = windowLoaded;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you visit this page in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari (desktop) you'll notice the `#hideMe` paragraph gets hidden, then the Javascript pushes `?back=true` into the browser's history.  Next, if you click the link you'll go to Google. From Google, click the back button.  In Chrome and Firefox the `#hideMe` paragraph will be displayed.  In Safari the paragraph will still be hidden.  If you click the reload button, Safari will actually reload the page and execute the Javascript.

You can also check the Javascript console and you'll see Safari never calls `windowLoaded` when you come back to the page from Google.

Is there any way to get Safari to run the Javascript when the user navigates to the page using their back button?

Comment: why don't you just use IIFE? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: @arslan2012 thanks for the idea.  I gave that a try adding this snippet to the Javascript above, `(function () { console.log("IIFE function executed."); })();`. Unfortunately I got the same results. The console shows the function being executed when I load the page but not when I get to it by hitting the back button.